# Resetting a variable to zero at the beginning of a new day

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot for dating. I have a LimitedSearch variable, and if a user searched for too many profiles in a day, it becomes 100 and limits the user's search for new profiles to a new day. It is assumed that at the beginning of each new day LimitedSearch will be equal to 0, how to organize this so that the entire program as a whole does not stop?

I tried a step where if at least one user uses the bot between 00:00 and 3:00 am, then LimitedSearch will be reset, but C#, as far as I understand, does not provide DateTime comparison capabilities

Comment: No, that's not true. .NET provides `DateTime` comparisons.

Comment: Just keep the history of the last 100 searches. If the date of the first one is today then don't allow any more searches.

Comment: You can reset the LimitedSearch counter at the beginning of each new day by periodically checking the current time and resetting it when a new day starts. To do this, you can use a background task or timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a combination of DateTime and a database.

storing LimitedSearch value in a database, guarantees that the value remains intact. If the limit for searching goes beyond 100, then let the user know that they've hit their daily search maximum when they browse profiles.

compare the stored time of the last reset to the current time every day, ideally at midnight. If the current time suggests that the reset happened earlier, update the time stored and set the LimitedSearch variable to 0.

the code below could give you an idea:

```
// Get the stored time of the last reset
DateTime lastResetTime = GetLastResetTimeFromDatabase();

// Get the current time
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

// Compare the current time with the stored time
if (currentTime.Date > lastResetTime.Date)
{
    // Reset the LimitedSearch variable to 0
    LimitedSearch = 0;

    // Update the stored time to the current time
    UpdateLastResetTimeInDatabase(currentTime);
}
// Continue with the rest of your logic
```